# How to integrate MSAL library from scratch with Angular js 1.x application

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, msal.js

We build our application based on AngularJS v1.8.2 and Java as a backend. Currently we have used keyclock for MFA. We have implemented everything from the backend.

Now we have to replace keycloak with MSAL. MSAL library does not support the Angular JS 1.x version.

Kindly help me to integrate MSAL into my application.

I have already registered our application in Azure.

Thanks & regards,
Ranjan Kumar Singh

Answer (score 0):

I am actually in the process of doing so, and I'm running into some issues with the redirect methods. The callback url after authenticating doesn't get handled, and I'm in the process of figuring out why. Since I'm using msal-browser, there might not be a way to do so and I have to do that manually? The code samples from the git repo is great and helps you understand the flow for the JS implementations, but I suspect that either angularjs 1.8 is doing something that might be affecting the callback, or maybe the angularjs hash "#" could be doing something too. I'm not too sure. But here's the link to the code samples and in there you see lots of documentations. The relevant ones are msal-browser and msal-common. The msal-angular does not support angularjs, the minimum is v2.

I'm currently trying to implement it as a service using a factory, then I'm trying to use that service in the main module config where I use urlRouterProvider.when('/') and in the controller. I haven't massaged out the full process yet as I'm still in having a few issues. So I'll try to update this when I do!

**Links:**
[msal-browser](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-browser)
[samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples)

**Update:**

I don't know how helpful this update is, but I got the callback url to be processed and the issue is resolved when using the `loginRedirect()` (other things still to handle like tokens). I'm not exactly sure how I did it, it's possible to be one or the combination of these things:

- I added `http://localhost:3000/#` to the azure AD redirect uri. So now I have both with and without the "#". And in the MSAL config object, I don't specify the redirectUri. (I have html5mode(false) btw, so it might be different for you).
- I added scopes to the azure AD and used them instead of just using arbitrary ones that I took from the sample code like `[User.Read]`. I don't think this made a big difference, because if the scopes were wrong, it wouldn't like it and it shows you a message about it.
- I added handling the events that get emitted from MSAL, inside the app module definition `.run()`, which I thought that fixed it, but it still works without them.

I will take another look later and hopefully see what I did to get it to work, but you also might not run into this issue at all.

Comment: Hi Batata,
Thank you for response. 
I am facing redirection url
Below are the steps I have used in my application. Let me know your suggestion

Comment: @RanjanSingh I can't comment on your reply. But I'm assuming it's redirecting to your login page because of this config option? `navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true`

Comment: Or is it redirecting to login before the tokens are set? In my case when I login, the callback uri is added /#/code=... and the `otherwise` was forcing navigation at that point before processing the uri and setting the tokens.

Comment: Yes its redirect to login page. I have added this navigateToLoginRequestUrl to capture the accessToken in $rootScope variable. 
the library is not storing the token automatically in browserLocalStorage/sessionStorage. 
Let me know if you will get the solution for it

Comment: I think I'm having a similar issue actually. But I'm still working on solving other issues with this upgrade and will get to this soon.

Comment: Sorry i can't edit comments, I meant to continue my comment:
...and update you. You let me know too if you figure something out. Also, your setup is interesting. What version of MSAL are you using? Are you calling the `initialize()` somewhere? And are you using the msalService in your code to determine if you're authenticated? and regarding the navigation to login page, I'm triggering `loginRedirect()` on a button click. So if the acquireToken() is triggering any of the redirect methods,that could be a reason? I haven't used angularjs much before, so I've had some issues using async/await

Comment: until I figured out using $q instead in combination of .then(). I have a different angular structure and using the msalService in urlRouterProvider func on the main app module definition to navigate to the login state if not auth, and if I am, an api resp determines transitionTo states. That's the first point of contact, so `$rootScope` won't be available for me, so I have to call one of the msal methods getActiveAccount() or getAllAccounts() to determine authentication state. Open for feedback if this isn't a great method with MSAL. But I'm just working with this already existing old code.

Comment: I replaced the MSAL library with Keycloak Authentication and connected to Azure AD via Keycloak. This change was necessary as we use more than three identity providers (Azure AD, Okta, etc.) for different customers. Keycloak offers the flexibility to connect with various identity providers. Now, the system is working smoothly, and we can successfully obtain the token after authentication. The flow is as follows:
UI -> KeyCloak -> Azure AD :--- receive the token back in UI
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I have thought about using a 3rd party, but not sure if it can be added to the scope of the project I'm working on. But I'm glad it worked out with this old angular tech! I might look into it anyway out of curiosity. Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response.

I have to use MSAL Library with Multiple Identity Providers (Azure AD, Keycloak, Okta, DB Login)

I'm working on implementing authentication with multiple identity providers using the MSAL library in an AngularJS application. Currently, I'm focusing on Azure AD. Here's an overview of the steps I've taken and the issue I'm facing:

**Step 1: Route Configuration**

I have set up a route configuration using $routeProvider.when('/') in my AngularJS application. When I access localhost:8080/abc, it correctly redirects to the login page.

```
mainApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/login/", {
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
    .when("/logout/", {
        templateUrl: "views/logout.html",
        controller: "LogoutController"
    })
    .when("/workbench/", {
        templateUrl: "views/workbench.html",
        controller: "WorkbenchController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/login/"
    });
)}
```

**Step 2: Redirect to Azure AD Login Page**
Upon accessing localhost:8080/abc, there is a brief redirection to the login page, and then it automatically redirects to the Azure AD login page.

```
mainApp.service("msalService", ["$q", function ($q) {
var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "4bhy65sv-cde1-3939-rtfhf9-a2b7356789327645",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/47582628-45982-4bb1-a3e5-583446725dsfdtjfdsbf",
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:8080/abc",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
};

var myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

return {
    acquireToken: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent({})
            .then(function (tokenResponse) {
                deferred.resolve(tokenResponse);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect({});
            });

            return deferred.promise;
    },

    logout: function () {
        myMSALObj.logout();
    },

    handleRedirectPromise: function () {
        return myMSALObj.handleRedirectPromise();
    },
};
},]);
```

Handle Redirect promise :-

```
mainApp.run(function (msalService, $location, $rootScope) {
msalService.handleRedirectPromise().then(function (response) {
    if (response) {
        console.log("Access token ---  ", response.accessToken);
        $rootScope.msalAccessToken = response.accessToken;
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Redirect handling failed", error);
});
});
```

MainController.js

```
 mainApp.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $rootScope, msalService, ) {
    $scope.doApiRequest = function(){
        msalService.acquireToken().then(function(tokenResponse){
            console.log("Token acquired", token);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.error("Token acquisition failed", error);
        });
    }
    
     $scope.doApiRequest();
});
```

**Step 3: Obtain Azure AD Token**

I've successfully used my Azure AD credentials to log in, obtained the token, and stored it in $rootScope. I've set this token in the request header for subsequent requests.

Authentication Interceptor is also on the page where I definde the $routeProvider

```
mainApp.service('authenticationInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope, $location, $cookies, $injector) {
    var service = this;
    var msalAccessTokenPromise = $injector.get("msalService").handleRedirectPromise();

    service.responseError = function(response, status) {
        if(!response.headers){
            return $q.reject(response);
        }

        // authorization.
        if (response.headers('Reason-Code') == 401) {
            $location.path('/unauthorized');
            return;
        } else if (response.config.url.indexOf('loginAuth') == -1 && response.status == 401) {

            if (!$rootScope.loggedOutProcessed) {
                $rootScope.logoutApp();
                RemoveUser();
                RemoveUserImage();
                $rootScope.showMessage('Your current session has expired.. Please login again..!!', 'User Session Expired', false);
                $rootScope.loggedOutProcessed = true;
            }
            return;
        }


        return $q.reject(response);
    };

    service.response = function(response) {
        if (response != undefined && response.headers != undefined && response.headers('RedirectToSSOLogin') === "true") {
            //redirect to login page
            window.location.href = appBaseUrl;
        } else if (response != undefined && response.headers != undefined && response.headers('RedirectToDblogin') === "true") {
                //redirect to login page
                $window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/abc/login/dblogin";
        }  else {
            return response;
        }
    };

    service.request = function(request) {
        var ssoLoginEnabled = $rootScope.ssoLoginEnabled;
        var dbLogin = $rootScope.dbLogin;
        var authToken = $cookies.get("X-Auth-Token");
        if (false && ssoLoginEnabled && !dbLogin && !authToken) {

            window.location.href = appBaseUrl;
            return request;
            
        } else {
            return $q.when(msalAccessTokenPromise).then(function (response) {
                var msalAccessToken = response ? response.accessToken : $rootScope.msalAccessToken;
                if (msalAccessToken) {
                    request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + msalAccessToken;
                }
                return request;
            });
        }
    };
})
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authenticationInterceptor');
}])
```

**Issue: Redirection to Application Login Page**

After completing the login steps, the application redirects back to the login page. I'm unsure why this is happening.

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Additionally, if you need more details or specific code snippets, please let me know.